# How to fix incorrect value dragged to the drop function using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have question regarding to my codes, can you recommend what is the problem with this.

The data dynamically from the database, i use foreach to list all item to the dragged div. so now my question for this.

Ex. I drag the Item one  with **Order Number #301764337** when i drop other item to the box the retrieve Order Number is **#301764337**  is same to the first value that i already drag that means is incorrect, Why it happen they get the same value rather than itself value? I have here my application image i will show you the output image

[image: Same Value]

As you can see the value that i retrieve is **301764337** same to the first value that i already drag to the first box.

I have here my **item list**

```
    @foreach($customer_orders_details as $transac_details)
    <div class="drag-wrapper from-launch" >
        <div class="card" style="opacity: 0.8" id="addStyleHover">
            <div class="card-body" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;" >
                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;">
                    <i class="far fa-user-circle" style="font-size:30px;"></i>
                    <br><br>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" id="numbers" style="font-weight: 300; color:black !important; font-family: 'Open Sans';">OR # {{$transac_details->or_number}}</h6>

                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: bold; color:black !important;">Customer: {{$transac_details->customer_name}}</h6>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="color:black !important;">Driver: {{$transac_details->driver_name}}</h6><br>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: 300;">Address: {{$transac_details->order_ship_address}}</h6>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: 300;">Contact #: {{$transac_details->customer_number}}</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Total:${{$transac_details->amount}}</p>

                    <input type="hidden" name="" class="or_number" value="{{$transac_details->or_number}}">

                    @if($transac_details->driver_name != "")
                        {{-- <button href="#" data-order-id='{{$transac_details->order_id}}' data-customer-id='{{$transac_details->customer_id}}' style="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#driver_assign" id="assign_btn" type="button" class="card-link btn btn-primary">Assign</button> --}}
                    @else
                        <button href="#" data-order-id='{{$transac_details->order_id}}' data-customer-id='{{$transac_details->customer_id}}' style="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#driver_assign" id="assign_btn" type="button" class="card-link btn btn-primary">Assign</button>
                    @endif

                    <button href="#" class="card-link btn btn-outline-warning" id="gather_customer_order" data-order-id='{{$transac_details->order_id}}' data-customer-id='{{$transac_details->customer_id}}' style="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customer_detail_delivery">Details</button>

                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

**My dropzone div**

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div id="dropZone">
        <div class="stack"  style="width:260px;">
            <div class="stackHdr" style="background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white;  text-align: center;">
                <text>In the Kitchen</text>
            </div>
            <center>
                <div class="stackDrop1" id="drop2" style="">

                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div id="dropZone">
        <div class="stack"  style="width:260px;">
            <div class="stackHdr" style="background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white;  text-align: center;">
                <text>On the Road</text>
            </div>
            <center>
                <div class="stackDrop2" style="">

                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div id="dropZone">
        <div class="stack"  style="width:260px;">
            <div class="stackHdr" style="background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white;  text-align: center;">
                <text>Completed</text>
            </div>
            <center>
                <div class="stackDrop3" style="">

                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Jquery:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){



  $(".drag-wrapper").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: 'clone'
  });

  $("#launchPad").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".drag-wrapper",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      // $("#launchPad").append($(ui.draggable));
    }
  });

  $(".stackDrop1").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".from-launch",
    revert: 'invalid',
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.removeClass("from-launch").addClass("from-kitchen");
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));

      console.log('In the kitchen');
      alert($('input.or_number').val());

    }

  });


  $(".stackDrop2").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".from-kitchen",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {

      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));

    }
  });

    $(".stackDrop3").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".from-kitchen",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.removeClass("from-kitchen").addClass("from-kitchen2");
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
      console.log('Completed');
    }
  });



});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some `jQuery` code, because I can't see where you are calling that `alert()`, but by just looking at your code, the problem is surely related to the fact your are repeating `ids`. Instead of using `ids` inside your `@foreach`, change them to clases. As you can see, right now, every time you drag your divs, it will return the value of the first found `id`, which is `#791527381`.

**UPDATE**

Please, try changing following code. for the one below. All I doing is adding a find, to see for the input inside the draggable.

**HTML**

```
<div class="drag-wrapper from-launch" >
    <div class="card addStyleHover" style="opacity: 0.8">
        <div class="card-body" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;" >
            <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;">
                <i class="far fa-user-circle" style="font-size:30px;"></i>
                <br><br>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted numbers" style="font-weight: 300; color:black !important; font-family: 'Open Sans';">OR # {{$transac_details->or_number}}</h6>

                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: bold; color:black !important;">Customer: {{$transac_details->customer_name}}</h6>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="color:black !important;">Driver: {{$transac_details->driver_name}}</h6><br>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: 300;">Address: {{$transac_details->order_ship_address}}</h6>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: 300;">Contact #: {{$transac_details->customer_number}}</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Total:${{$transac_details->amount}}</p>

                <input type="hidden" name="" class="or_number" value="{{$transac_details->or_number}}">

                @if($transac_details->driver_name != "")
                    {{-- <button href="#" data-order-id='{{$transac_details->order_id}}' data-customer-id='{{$transac_details->customer_id}}' style="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#driver_assign" type="button" class="card-link btn btn-primary assign_btn">Assign</button> --}}
                @else
                    <button href="#" data-order-id='{{$transac_details->order_id}}' data-customer-id='{{$transac_details->customer_id}}' style="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#driver_assign" type="button" class="card-link btn btn-primary assign_btn">Assign</button>
                @endif

                <button href="#" class="card-link btn btn-outline-warning gather_customer_order" data-order-id='{{$transac_details->order_id}}' data-customer-id='{{$transac_details->customer_id}}' style="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customer_detail_delivery">Details</button>

            </h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".stackDrop1").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".from-launch",
    revert: 'invalid',
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.removeClass("from-launch").addClass("from-kitchen");
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
      console.log('In the kitchen');
      alert($(this).find('.or_number').val());
    }
});
```

Comment: @Hi Alain, where in my codes need to change to class?

Comment: Instead of using `id` inside your foreach, change them for class. For example, instead of:
`<input type="hidden" name="" id="or_number" value="{{$transac_details->or_number}}">`
Do ->
`<input type="hidden" name="" class="or_number" value="{{$transac_details->or_number}}">`

Comment: Cool, maybe we can find it in the rest of the code.

Comment: take a look the new update on my jquery code and foreach thanks alain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187535/discussion-between-devge-and-alain-cruz).